# Deploy Prod pipeline to Non-prod

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can we export prod synapse pipeline into non-prod?

If so, how to do it?
My approach - I think copying json code of prod and deploying in non-prod can work.
Please clarify if my approach is correct or if anyone have some other approach will be a great help.

Another question, is there any complication happen if we deploy prod pipeline to non-prod. If yes, what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to clone a pipeline from 1 adf to another :

1. json extraction of individual components like dataset, linked services etc associated with pipeline and creating them in another adf in a sequential way. This is too much of manual effort
2. export the template specific to that pipeline via portal which would download it in zip format. Then import that in another ADF. This would take care of all aspect with a single import.

W.r.t your 2nd query, ideally your preprod Or non prod is superset and prod is a subset.
So ideally just cloning a specific pipeline from prod to lower env would not be an issue